# Understanding SSTable implementation

Tags: database, algorithm, theory

I am looking at an explanation for how SSTable are implemented.

[image]

> This means you can jump to the offset for handbag and **scan from there**
>   until you find handiwork (or not, if the key is not present in the
>   file).

I don't understand the highlighted part. If we know just offset for a given key, how do we scan until we find the desired key? As we slide through the bytes after the key, how do we know if we've enocuntered a new key, or if we're looking at a really big value?

Answer (score 2):

Scylla describes one implementation [in their docs](https://docs.scylladb.com/architecture/sstable/sstable3/sstables_3_index/). (I don't have any connection with Scylla. I just happened to have this handy.) They store the key length for index entries (not exactly what you're looking for) in their `index_entry` structure.

```
struct index_file {
    struct index_entry entries[];
};

struct index_entry {
    be16 key_length;
    char key[key_length];
    varint position; // decoded into a 64-bit integer
    varint promoted_index_length; // decoded into a 32-bit integer
    byte promoted_index[promoted_index_length];
};
```

If your implementation supports keys of varying lengths--as I think all commercial-grade SSTable implentations do--it's common to store their length. In general, software that stores "things" of varying lengths uses a data structure that includes the length of the "thing". (Scylla probably uses a Java iterator.)

Answer (score 1):

The length of each entry is also stored so that you can iterate over the entries.

https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/863f185970eff21e826e5fe1164a6215a515c23b/table/block.cc#L238

https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/863f185970eff21e826e5fe1164a6215a515c23b/table/block.cc#L61